# How to populate a ListBox with contents of a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, radgrid

I would like to loop through a column in a grid and display it's contents in a listbox.  Here's what I have so far:

```
protected void btnPopulateList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var docStats = new List<string>();

        foreach (GridDataItem item in rgDocRvwrs.Items)
        {
            docStats.Add(item["stat"].ToString());
        }
        statListBox.DataSource = docStats;
        statListBox.DataBind();
    }
```

The problem with the above code is that while it populates the list box with the appropriate number of items, the items aren't the values.  Instead they are `Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableCell`.

If I change the above code to `docStats.Add(item.FindControl("stat").ToString());`, I get an null reference exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I modify the code above to populate the list box with the values of the "stat" column?

Below is an example of the table structure:

```
+---------+----------+---------+
|   ID    |    stat  |    Opt  |
+---------+----------+---------+
|    1    | Assigned |   Done  |
+---------+----------+---------+
|    2    | Declined |   Done  |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: If it's a GridTableCell you can still access the item. https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/api/server/Telerik.Web.UI/GridTableCell

Comment: something like `((GridTableCell)item).Item.DataItem`. The DataItem is the original DataItem provided by the datasource

Comment: Thanks @Schadensbegrenzer - you put me on the right track.  I was able to find the following that does exactly what I needed ... https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/selecting/cell-selection/defaultcs.aspx